# Finding the leading exponent of a binary number

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, binary

Let's say that the binary representation of a number $k$ is $2^{X_n} + 2^{X_{n-1}} + \dots + 2^{X_0}$ with each term in this polynomial having a $1$ or $0$ multiplied to it (I just haven't showed them here).

Now, given only $k$, and no other information, is there a way that I can find the number $X_n$(which is the highest degree of the binary representation of $k$)?

Comment: Since you are writing the terms as $2^{X_k}$ rather than $2^k$, you can assume that these are precisely the nonzero terms that appear in the binary expansion, right? So there is no "$0$ or $1$ multiplier" that is being suppressed. These are exactly the terms with a multiplier of $1$ and the zero terms are not even written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the highest power of $2$ that appears is $2^n$. Then the smallest $k$ could be is $2^n$, which would happen if all the lower binary digits of $k$ were $0$. On the other hand, the largest $k$ could be is if all the other digits were $1$, which is the value $2^{n+1}-1$ (that's because if you add $1_2$ to $1111\cdots 1_2$, you get $1000\cdots 0_2$). Thus

$$2^n \leq k <2^{n+1}$$

Taking logs with base $2$, this gives

$$n \leq \log_2 k < n+1$$

Since $n$ is integral, this means

$$\boxed{n=\lfloor\log_2 k\rfloor}$$

This says that $k$ has $1 + \lfloor\log_2 k\rfloor$ necessary digits in its binary expansion (assuming $k\neq 0$ is integral).

Comment: You saved the day man! Thanks a lot. This was just the answer I was expecting. I needed this very answer because this is the logarithmic time when you run a looping code which calculates the binary expansion of a decimal number. THANKS :)

Comment: You're quite welcome. Note that the same argument works for any base $b$, just change the base of the logarithm to "$\log_b$" to match the base (radix) of the expansion.